# Table alignment changes when changing font size (STATA's etable output)

Tags: tables, multicolumn, tabulary

I have exported a table from STATA using etable option. I changed the font size to tiny to fit the table to the document page and used the option centering. However, it disrupts the entire formatting of the table. Is there an alternative to doing it? I have tried using the table, tabularx, and tabulary. None of them seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

```
\tiny
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
\cline{1-11}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Excellent} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{V.Good} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Good} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fair} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Poor} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\
\cline{1-11}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Prior heart attack} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.301} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.057} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.153} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.137} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.069} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.023)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.012)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.010)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Number of people in household} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.008} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.001} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.004} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.004} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.002} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.003)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.000)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.001)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.001)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.001)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Body mass index (BMI)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.006} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.001} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.003} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.003} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.001} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.001)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.000)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.000)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.000)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.000)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Diabetes status} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.235} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.044} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.119} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.107} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.054} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.022)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.005)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.012)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.010)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.005)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{30-39} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.024} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.001} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.013} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.007} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.003} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.014)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.001)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.008)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.004)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.002)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{40-49} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.098} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.007} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.057} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.035} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.014} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.015)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.003)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.009)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.002)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{50-59} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.185} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.043} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.106} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.086} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.036} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.012)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.007)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.007)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.003)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{60-69} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.237} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.084} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.125} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.133} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.063} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.010)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.007)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.004)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{70+} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.248} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.096} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.127} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.146} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.071} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.012)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.009)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.011)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.007)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Black} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.165} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.031} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.083} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.075} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.037} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.013)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.003)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.007)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.006)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.003)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Female} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.039} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{-0.007} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.020} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.018} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.009} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{**} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.008)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.002)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.004)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.004)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &
  \multicolumn{1}{r}{(0.002)} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
\cline{1-11}
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize{
** p$<$.01, * p$<$.05
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to export data to R and use one of its plugins `kable` (see the [manual](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf)), which produces quite decent tables.

The problem with the generated code in question is too many columns making the table very wide. This is why you have to use very small font to fit it. The other issue is related to code as it contains plenty of redundant content.

In the example below, there two macros `\pone` and `\ptwo` which add annotations--see the first value. I noticed the same `p < 0.05` is reported across the whole table except one row. Wouldn't it be easier to report what is NOT `p < 0.05`, instead? As an example, I put a "dagger" in that row and annotation that explains its meaning. There's also a custom length which control spacing between main values and keep statistics with uncertainties together.

The code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\pone{\rlap{\textsuperscript{*}}}
\newcommand\ptwo{\rlap{\textsuperscript{**}}}
\newlength\vdist\setlength\vdist{4pt}
\setlength\cmidrulewidth{0.3pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \setlength\tabcolsep{9pt}
  \newcommand\xth[1]{\makebox[0pt][c]{\normalsize#1}}
  %
  \small
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}\label{tab:label-for-table}
  \vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l @{\hspace{2em}} *5{c} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \xth{Excellent} & \xth{V. Good} & \xth{Good} & \xth{Fair} & \xth{Poor} \\
    \midrule
    Prior heart attack
    & -0.301\ptwo  & -0.057  & 0.153   & 0.137   & 0.069 \\
    & (0.023) & (0.006) & (0.012) & (0.010) & (0.006) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist]
    Number of people in
    & -0.008  & -0.001  & 0.004   & 0.004   & 0.002 \\
    household & (0.003) & (0.000) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist] 
    Body mass index (BMI)
    & -0.006  & -0.001  & 0.003   & 0.003   & 0.001 \\
    & (0.001) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist] 
    Diabetes status
    & -0.235  & -0.044  & 0.119   & 0.107   & 0.054 \\
    & (0.022) & (0.005) & (0.012) & (0.010) & (0.005) \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
    30-39$^{\dag}$
    & -0.024  & 0.001   & 0.013   & 0.007   & 0.003 \\
    & (0.014) & (0.001) & (0.008) & (0.004) & (0.002) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist] 
    40-49
    & -0.098  & -0.007  & 0.057   & 0.035   & 0.014 \\
    & (0.015) & (0.003) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.002) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist] 
    50-59
    & -0.185  & -0.043  & 0.106   & 0.086   & 0.036 \\
    & (0.012) & (0.006) & (0.007) & (0.007) & (0.003) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist] 
    60-69
    & -0.237  & -0.084  & 0.125   & 0.133   & 0.063 \\
    & (0.010) & (0.006) & (0.006) & (0.007) & (0.004) \\ \addlinespace[\vdist] 
    70+
    & -0.248  & -0.096  & 0.127   & 0.146   & 0.071 \\
    & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.011) & (0.007) \\ \cmidrule{2-6}
    Black
    & -0.165  & -0.031  & 0.083   & 0.075   & 0.037 \\
    & (0.013) & (0.003) & (0.007) & (0.006) & (0.003) \\  \addlinespace[\vdist]
    Female
    & -0.039  & -0.007  & 0.020   & 0.018   & 0.009 \\
    & (0.008) & (0.002) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.002) \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\footnotesize $^{\dag}$ $p < 0.05$ except for this row}\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]